# Jetty 9.1.2 Https Connector Selenium maven tests fail in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jetty

I have below jetty maven plugin config in pom.xml-

```
<artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.2.v20140210</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Added for https connector -->
                <jettyXml>${project.basedir}/jetty.xml,
jetty-  http.xml,jetty-ssl.xml,jetty-https.xml</jettyXml>
```

I use following settings in Jenkins-
-Djetty.port=12854 -Dupdate.trunk=1 -Dupdate.trunk=1 -Djetty.stopport=16657

and use below maven plugin for running integration tests-

```
maven-failsafe-plugin:2.16:integration-test
```

I have copied all jetty xmls from -
http://juplo.de/configure-https-for-jetty-maven-plugin-9-0-x/
and changed the https connector port to 19854. 
I have selenium tests configured for https protocol and 19854 port, and they run in local with firefox webdriver without any issue.

Problems-
1) When I do not send maven arguments -Djetty.port, it takes default port 8080 and fails to start jetty with error - port already in use.

2) When I specify port, I see below in Jenkins-
    and jenkins opens http and https-

```
Started ServerConnector@7eb879b8{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:12854}

INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:pool-1-thread-1 for channel: 
Started   ServerConnector@56eafbb4{SSL-http/1.1}{0.0.0.0:19854}
```

but tests fail- with following error

```
WARN:oejh.HttpParser:qtp2005308873-112: badMessage: 400 
Illegal   character for HttpChannelOverHttp@1bf94c90{r=0,a=IDLE,uri=-}
```

and I see below url in the jenkins test log-

```
https://localhost:12854/
```

where as it should be

```
https://localhost:19854/
```

How do I get this working in Jenkins?
I appreciate the help.